# How can I get my Windows 8 license key once I've installed Windows 10 preview?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I installed Windows 10 preview but now I want to re-install Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 How can I get my license key back so that I can do this? The computer was supplied with Windows 8 pre-installed.

Comment: If you don't have the key, or any sort of recovery media, then contact the manufacturer for either the key, or their restore media. OEM licensing requires them to support the licensing on the computers they sell.

Comment: Windows 8.0 and Windows 8.1 are stored in firmware on your computer.  You extract them in an identical way.  You can also just install the same version of Windows your computer came with and the key will automatically be detected.

Answer (score 0):

If your Win8 was pre-installed the key is usually integrated in the UEFI bios of the computer. If that is the case Windows 8/8.1 will detect the key during installation and automatically use it.

If this is NOT the case the key should be listed on a label attached to the computer. (Could be on the inside or bottom of the housing. In case of a laptop it is sometimes hidden beneath the battery.)

One of the 2 cases above should be valid. If not contact your vendor.
They should provide the key. If they won't or can't they are frauds.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  There are numerous methods to determine the key without having to contact the vendor, whom I might add, wouldn't know the key anyways.

Comment: @Ramhound He needs to know the key for re-install. But maybe he doesn't need the key for that. That is what I explained to him. I fail to see why that warrants a downvote. I may not have literally answered the question, but I answered to his intended purpose. As for the vendor not knowing the key: The pre-install may have used a generic key which the manufacturer can't disclose, but they MUST have supplied a specific key for the system. It should be listed on the system, stored in Bios, or be available on request... Continue next comment...

Comment: Continued... EU law mandates that the vendor must support the customer, if necessary contact the manufacturer directly. In practice most vendors try to avoid doing anything after you have paid for your purchase, but that is a different matter. Law may be different in other countries.

Comment: "I may not have literally answered the question" - that is the percise reason for the way I voted.  He specifically states he wants to reinstall Windows 8.0, and thus believes he needs the key, and you admit your answer does not answer that question.